# disable buttons permanently throughout the aplication in android

Tags: android, button

Actually i have 3 buttons.User should click on any one button then all the 3 buttons should disable permanently throughout the app(when we close and open the app, buttons should be in disable state).How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use sharedPreference to save the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the behavior in SharePreferences:

for example use this in `onResume`:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean enabled = pref.getBoolean("isEnabled",true);
myButton.setEnabled(enabled);
```

in `onClick` event of the button do this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
pref.edit().putBoolean("isEnabled",false).commit();
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: i tried the above code but it is working when ever on Resume method called

Comment: onResume always get called

Answer (score 1):

Use shared preference to store the clicked state of button.And check the preference value each time in activity/ fragment and disable or enable as per preference value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save your button state in sharedpreferences and based on your condition you need to enable / disable it in your activity code.

```
if(stateofbuttonfromprefs) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SharedPreference** for your purpose. For more information refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

> declare SharedPreference before onCreate method

```
SharedPreferences stateButton;
SharedPreferences.Editor bEditor;
```

> initialize this on onCreate()

```
stateButton= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Button_State", 0);
bEditor = stateButton.edit();
```

> add these two methods on your activity

```
public void setBState(boolean e) {
    bEditor.putBoolean("btn_state", e);
    bEditor.commit();
}

public boolean getButState(){
    return stateButton.getBoolean("btn_state", true);
}
```

> call this to know your button state call

```
but.setEnabled(getBState());
```

> when you need to disable the button, use

```
setBState(false);
```

Comment: @Naveen..It is working my side...post your code(Edit your question) for better understanding of your problem

Comment: @Naveen..You have to set setBState(false); in your all button onclicklistener

Comment: I have to set all the 3 buttons disable permanently when the user clicks any one button.

Answer (score 0):

> On Button click

```
button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("btn_click", true).commit();
        }
    });
```

> In Activity OnCreate method

```
Boolean btnClick= prefs.getBoolean("btn_click", false);
if(btnClick){
     //Disable Button
}else{
     //Enable Button
}
```