# Set button Enabled to false in Listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to disable my button in listview for that specific row after it is clicked.
For now, I can disable it but after I restart the activity it became clickable again. Below is the code for my adapter. Please let me know how I can do it, Thanks!

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Typeface face_02 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "customfont/grb.otf");
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
            holder.Boothname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Boothname);
            holder.buttonVote= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonvote);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        BoothClassFunAward product = productList.get(position);

        holder.Boothname.setText(product.getBoothName());
        holder.Boothname.setTypeface(face_02);
        holder.buttonVote.setTypeface(face_02);

        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;


        holder.buttonVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalHolder.buttonVote.setText("Completed");
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, ProgramActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent2);
            }
    });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155211/disable-buttons-permanently-throughout-the-aplication-in-android

Comment: what do you mean by this >>>  For now, I can disable it but after I restart the activity it became clickable again.

Comment: I think you will have to save the flag. Are you saving the data for each product?

Comment: @SharartiKAKA I mean I can use finalHolder.buttonVote.setEnabled(false); to disable the button after I click the button. But it is clickable again after I restart the Activity.

Comment: @EbyCloudins Nop. no Data change

Comment: did you get the solution of your problem ?

Comment: @SharartiKAKA Not yet :(

Comment: Why it is simple

Comment: @KingsleyMitchell how?

Comment: I have given the code below

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the boolean on button click on first time. You can enabled and disabled based on that.

For disable:

```
holder.buttonVote.setEnabled(false);
```

For Enabled:

```
holder.buttonVote.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: The questions says it resets on the activity reload

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios.

- **If the data i.e the list to be shown in list view is received from server**

If you are receiving the data from server then to maintain the state of the button you will have to add a boolean flag in the response you receive from server that weather the button has been clicked or not. As it is obvious that the button correspond to an action,Hence on the same note you will have to update the server about the status of button being clicked too in the same action.

- **The entire operation is local and no server interaction is done.**

For that you will have to rely on local database or shared preference.
Please make sure to do following things

1. Add an boolean flag in you pojo class thus each object in the list
   will  have a flag to represent it state.
2. Change the status of your flag once you click the button,Hence as per point 1 only the flag status of the selected object will change and rest will remain unaffected.
3. Notify your list.You will used this object to decide wether to keep 
   the button enabled or disabled.
4. Save the list so that entire changes persist if you uses that
   list next time.

You can either use database or shared preference to save the list.

Comment: Lol I got marked down for saying the same thing Armardeep.

Comment: Although i agree,you have mentioned the same component to be used. but the approach i have mentioned is different. I do not ask for maintaining a separate variable in preference for each position in the list.that will be a tiresome task and cannot be maintained easily. instead of that i prefer using a extra variable in the bean class itself. and save the entire list in preference.GSON can be used to save the list in the preferences. and further more if the data size is too huge to be locally maintained using preference. one can opt for database too.Further more go through the first point too.

Comment: You could do it like that too I suppose but I think they are equidistant because if you want to change button in the list you will need to resave whole list instead of the right key pair

Comment: Dabatase  I don't think would be good, too much set up for little reward